# Why does the org.geoserver.extension block my Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, geoserver, geotools

I try to transform a EPSG:900913 geometry object into a EPSG:4326. For achieving this I use this code:

```
    CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
    CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:900913");

    MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS, true);
```

When I executed the test application it threw this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException: No code "EPSG:900913" from authority "European Petroleum Survey Group" found for object of type "CoordinateReferenceSystem".
at org.geotools.referencing.factory.AbstractAuthorityFactory.noSuchAuthorityCode(AbstractAuthorityFactory.java:951)
at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.DirectEpsgFactory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(DirectEpsgFactory.java:2102)
```

So googled and found the solution: It needs a dependency for the "WPS Extension" for GeoTools. Therefore I inserted this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geoserver.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>gs-wps-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Strangely when I use this dependency, my Spring Boot Application is blocked, asking for a user/password combination like this [image: a user/password combination]

Why does the library block my entire web application and how can I prevent this kind of strange behavior?

EDIT - The dependency tree

```
 +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
 |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
 +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:test
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.6:compile
 |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.3:compile
 |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
 +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
 +- org.apache.commons:commons-csv:jar:1.2:compile
 +- org.openstreetmap.osmosis:osmosis-core:jar:0.44.1:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-lgpl:jar:4.4.1:compile
 |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
 |  +- net.sf.jpf:jpf:jar:1.5:compile
 |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
 |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.9:compile
 +- org.openstreetmap.osmosis:osmosis-pbf:jar:0.44.1:compile
 |  \- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.6.1:compile
 +- org.openstreetmap.osmosis:osmosis-pbf2:jar:0.44.1:compile
 +- org.openstreetmap.osmosis:osmosis-osm-binary:jar:0.44.1:compile
 +- org.openstreetmap.osmosis:osmosis-extract:jar:0.44.1:compile
 |  +- org.openstreetmap.osmosis:osmosis-apidb:jar:0.44.1:compile
 |  |  \- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.36:runtime
 |  +- org.openstreetmap.osmosis:osmosis-xml:jar:0.44.1:compile
 |  \- org.openstreetmap.osmosis:osmosis-replication:jar:0.44.1:compile
 |     \- org.openstreetmap.osmosis:osmosis-set:jar:0.44.1:compile
 +- org.openstreetmap.osmosis:osmosis-hstore-jdbc:jar:0.44.1:compile
 |  \- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.4-1201-jdbc4:compile
 +- org.openstreetmap.osmosis:osmosis-dataset:jar:0.44.1:compile
 +- org.openstreetmap.osmosis:osmosis-pgsnapshot:jar:0.44.1:compile
 |  +- org.postgis:postgis-jdbc:jar:1.3.3:compile
 |  +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
 |  |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
 |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:compile
 |  |  |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:compile
 |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.14:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.28:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.28:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:8.0.28:compile
 |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.0.28:compile
 |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.6:compile
 |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.4.6:compile
 |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.4.6:compile
 |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.3.Final:compile
 |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
 |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
 |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.7:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.0.28:compile
 |  |     \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.0.28:compile
 |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
 |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  \- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
 |  |     +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.8:compile
 |  |     \- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
 |  \- nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:jar:1.2.9:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.2.7.RELEASE:test
 |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
 |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
 |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
 +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.7.4.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.9.4.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.8.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.7:compile
 |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.12:compile
 |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
 +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1:compile
 +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
 |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
 |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
 |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
 |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
 |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
 |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
 |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
 |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
 |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
 |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
 +- org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial:jar:4.3:compile
 |  \- com.vividsolutions:jts:jar:1.13:compile
 +- postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.1-901.jdbc4:compile
 +- com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.5.7:compile
 +- org.geotools:gt-shapefile:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
 |  +- org.geotools:gt-data:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
 |  +- org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1.3:compile
 |  \- javax.media:jai_core:jar:1.1.3:compile
 +- org.geotools:gt-swing:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
 |  +- org.geotools:gt-referencing:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
 |  |  +- com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:core:jar:0.26:compile
 |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-metadata:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.geotools:gt-opengis:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
 |  |  +- jgridshift:jgridshift:jar:1.0:compile
 |  |  \- net.sf.geographiclib:GeographicLib-Java:jar:1.44:compile
 |  +- org.geotools:gt-render:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
 |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-coverage:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.affine:jt-affine:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.iterators:jt-iterators:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.utilities:jt-utilities:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- it.geosolutions.jaiext.scale:jt-scale:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  |     \- it.geosolutions.jaiext.translate:jt-translate:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.algebra:jt-algebra:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.bandmerge:jt-bandmerge:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.bandselect:jt-bandselect:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.bandcombine:jt-bandcombine:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.border:jt-border:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.buffer:jt-buffer:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.crop:jt-crop:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.lookup:jt-lookup:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.mosaic:jt-mosaic:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.nullop:jt-nullop:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.rescale:jt-rescale:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.stats:jt-stats:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.warp:jt-warp:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.zonal:jt-zonal:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.binarize:jt-binarize:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.format:jt-format:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.colorconvert:jt-colorconvert:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.errordiffusion:jt-errordiffusion:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.orderdither:jt-orderdither:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.colorindexer:jt-colorindexer:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.imagefunction:jt-imagefunction:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.piecewise:jt-piecewise:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.classifier:jt-classifier:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jaiext.rlookup:jt-rlookup:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  |  \- it.geosolutions.jaiext.vectorbin:jt-vectorbin:jar:1.0.8:compile
 |  |  \- org.geotools:gt-cql:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
 |  \- com.miglayout:miglayout:jar:swing:3.7:compile
 +- org.geotools:gt-epsg-hsql:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
 |  \- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.3.3:compile
 \- org.geoserver.extension:gs-wps-core:jar:2.8-SNAPSHOT:compile
    +- org.geoserver:gs-wfs:jar:2.8-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  +- org.geoserver:gs-main:jar:2.8-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  |  +- org.geoserver:gs-ows:jar:2.8-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  |  |  \- xpp3:xpp3:jar:1.1.3.4.O:compile
    |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile
    |  |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1:compile
    |  |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
    |  |  +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.23:compile
    |  |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
    |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-jdbc:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-wfs-ng:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-complex:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  |  |  |  \- org.geotools:gt-app-schema-resolver:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  |  |  +- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
    |  |  |  \- xmlunit:xmlunit:jar:1.3:compile
    |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-property:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-wms:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  |  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.7:compile
    |  |  |  \- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
    |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.3:compile
    |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-imagemosaic:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-transform:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  |  |  +- org.jaitools:jt-vectorbinarize:jar:1.4.0:compile
    |  |  |  \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.6.2:compile
    |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
    |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
    |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
    |  |  +- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.8:compile
    |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:1.46:compile
    |  +- org.geotools.ogc:net.opengis.wfs:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  |  +- org.geotools.ogc:org.w3.xlink:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  |  \- org.geotools.ogc:net.opengis.fes:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  +- org.geotools.xsd:gt-xsd-wfs:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  |  \- org.geotools.xsd:gt-xsd-fes:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  +- org.geotools.xsd:gt-xsd-filter:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  |  \- org.geotools.xsd:gt-xsd-gml2:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  \- net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.2.3:compile
    |     +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
    |     \- net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:jar:1.0.6:compile
    +- org.geoserver:gs-wcs2_0:jar:2.8-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  +- org.geoserver:gs-wcs:jar:2.8-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-gtopo30:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  |  \- org.geotools:gt-image:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  +- org.geotools.ogc:net.opengis.wcs:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  \- org.geotools.xsd:gt-xsd-wcs:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |     \- org.geotools:gt-xml:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |        \- org.apache.xml:xml-commons-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
    +- org.geoserver:gs-wcs1_1:jar:2.8-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  +- org.geotools.xsd:gt-xsd-gml3:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:compile
    |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
    +- org.geoserver:gs-wcs1_0:jar:2.8-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  \- org.geotools.xsd:gt-xsd-ows:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    +- org.geotools.ogc:net.opengis.wps:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  +- org.geotools.ogc:net.opengis.ows:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  +- net.java.dev.jsr-275:jsr-275:jar:1.0-beta-2:compile
    |  +- org.eclipse.emf:common:jar:2.6.0:compile
    |  \- org.eclipse.emf:ecore:jar:2.6.1:compile
    +- org.geotools.xsd:gt-xsd-wps:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    +- org.geotools.xsd:gt-xsd-sld:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  \- org.geotools.xsd:gt-xsd-core:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |     +- org.geotools:gt-graph:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |     +- picocontainer:picocontainer:jar:1.2:compile
    |     +- commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3:compile
    |     \- org.eclipse.xsd:xsd:jar:2.6.0:compile
    +- org.geotools:gt-process:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  \- javax.media:jai_imageio:jar:1.1:compile
    +- org.geotools:gt-process-raster:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  +- org.jaitools:jt-zonalstats:jar:1.4.0:compile
    |  +- org.jaitools:jt-rangelookup:jar:1.4.0:compile
    |  +- org.jaitools:jt-contour:jar:1.4.0:compile
    |  |  \- org.jaitools:jt-attributeop:jar:1.4.0:compile
    |  +- org.jaitools:jt-vectorize:jar:1.4.0:compile
    |  \- org.jaitools:jt-utils:jar:1.4.0:compile
    +- org.geotools:gt-process-geometry:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    +- org.geotools:gt-process-feature:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    +- org.geotools:gt-arcgrid:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  \- it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext-arcgrid:jar:1.1.12:compile
    |     +- it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext-streams:jar:1.1.12:compile
    |     \- it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext-utilities:jar:1.1.12:compile
    +- org.geotools:gt-geotiff:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  \- it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext-tiff:jar:1.1.12:compile
    |     \- it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext-geocore:jar:1.1.12:compile
    +- org.geotools:gt-geojson:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  +- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile
    |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
    +- org.geotools:gt-grid:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:17.0:compile
    +- org.geoserver:gs-platform:jar:2.8-SNAPSHOT:compile
    |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
    |  \- javax.media:jai_codec:jar:1.1.3:compile
    +- org.geotools:gt-api:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
    \- org.geotools:gt-main:jar:14-SNAPSHOT:compile
```

Comment: Please post the output of `mvn dependency:tree`. Most probably, the gs-wps-core library depends on Spring Security. If Spring Boot detects Spring Security on the classpath, it will be autoconfigured with a default username and password (which will be printed in the application log).

Comment: @dunni I've edited my question and inserted the dependency tree as suggested by you. Thanks!

Comment: @dunni Many thanks, you're idea about the security dependency was right. The WPS Extension has Spring Security as dependencies. I excluded them and now my app works again. But I ask myself why they added a security lib inside a simple geometry transformation extension??? Anyway, now it works.

Comment: I added it as an answer and also an additional method to disable security without excluding the dependencies. The extension depends on the core geoserver, which as a full server application includes also security management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably, the gs-wps-core library depends on Spring Security. If Spring Boot detects Spring Security on the classpath, it will be autoconfigured with a default username and password (which will be printed in the application log).

You can disable the security configuration by adding the following property to your application.properties file:

```
security.basic.enabled=false
```

Comment: Thanks dunni! I've solved it by exclusion of the security spring dependencies, but you're solution sounds more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you only need to add a dependency on one of the gt-epsg providers to get access to the GeoTools reprojection code. The most usual one is **gt-epsg-hsql** but there may be issues if you have other HSQL modules in use. That way you don't need to add any spring modules which only live in the GeoServer code.

For a fuller explanation of the issues see the [georeferencing FAQ](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/faq.html).